# How to have Chrome render a page emulating a viewport

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, viewport

I am working on a Chrome extension and I am running into the following issue. I would like to resize a tab to a specific width and height, but want to override the automatic resizing of elements. So I figured I should either somehow override the onresize event or instruct chrome to render the page while manipulating the (perceieved) viewport.

For some reason I cannot find anything to perform the former and on the latter, I have found a lot of information on the meta viewport tag but for some reason cannot make it work.
See also: [Dynamic viewport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8469255/dynamic-viewport) and [Can I change the viewport meta tag in mobile safari on the fly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588628/can-i-change-the-viewport-meta-tag-in-mobile-safari-on-the-fly?lq=1)

To give an example how do I render this page as if it was in a window(/tab) of e.g. 600 pixels wide even though the actual tab is 1200 or whatever amount of pixels wide (and being resized, either programmatically or manually)?

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" id="viewport" content="width = 600, height = device-height, maximum scale = 1.0, minimum-scale = 1.0">
    <title>Viewport testing</title>
</head>
<body>
<div style="width: 90%; border: solid 3px;">Current Viewport: <script>document.write(document.documentElement.offsetWidth.toString());</script> pixels</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The 600 is completely ignored and the div resizes while resizing the tab/window.

Am I overlooking something in the Chrome API?

The goal of this particular function of the extension is to be able to select an element (e.g. a div) or region (with crosshairs) of a webpage and resize the tab to show just that. I have everything working fine (selection etc, resizing and scrolling , detecting the element size etc etc) but obviously all responsive elements would be changed upon a window resize. I want to prevent that from happening.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do that through the api and it seems unlikely anything like that would exist, simply for security reasons (eg. arbitrarily resizing tab viewports which would frustrate users). I'd suggest doing something like overlaying an opaque div or something like that over the webpage (probably going to need 4 divs). While that's a terrible solution, I don't see how else you could do this without modifying the DOM or replacing all other elements with emtpy elements of the same size.

Comment: According to [this](http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/metaviewport/), `device-height` is available in theory but does not work. I think you can omit it? Also, I'm very suspicious of spaces in your `content` value, I don't think they are allowed. Can you try only `"width=600"`?

Comment: @IvyLynx, I was afraid of that, but looking for confirmation. I don;t share your view on the security issue though, there's plenty of opportunity in Javascript/DOM to annoy users (remember the web in 1998?) but the extension needs permission from the user.

Comment: @Xan, I copy pasted that, tried this as well but also does not work:
 <meta name="viewport" id="viewport" content="width=1600, height=1200, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
The meta tag seems to be completely ignored by Chrome.

Comment: @mvdwrd that's true, there's plenty of stuff that can _annoy_ users but it just gives me a feeling of _insecure_. I can't really come up with an example, just my assumption. Is this for mobile or desktop chrome btw, i'm a bit confused.

Comment: @IvyLynx, the funny thing is, the Chrome dev tools already have an emulation function which heavily modifies the viewport. I just cannot find anything on how to tap into the underlying API.

It is for desktop Chrome btw. the idea is that on a large monitor sometimes I want to have some video, table, article, reference etc side by side with something else (other browser tab, IDE or whatever). In stead of manually dragging the tab out of the main chrome window, resizing the tab and scrolling to make it fit I just click my extension, and hover over the page, click the (e.g.) DIV and presto.

Comment: @mvdwrd Firefox has the same capability through the dev tools, but in my months and months of scrying XPCOM I haven't found anything that would do this right off the bat and XPCOM tends to be on the more powerful side than the chrome api, which is more restricted. the [window api](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows) is the closest I found by browsing the chrome api and it seems it (embaressingly for me, considering my previous statement) allows resizing the window just fine. Nothing on viewports though.