# Dynamic Viewport/scale up down with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, viewport, mobile-website

I have a web widget that can be deployed on different mobile sites.

it is a widget that opens as full screen jquery.colorbox and display some dynamic content.

as mobile website can differs - sometimes the mobile browser can scale down - in order to fit all content. this causes a problem - as my widget than opens much smaller (texts/font extc.)

My widget opens on click on full screen - and its inject content into website code (not an iframe).
I am looking for a way to change the viewport dynamically and on the fly- and enable an option to return to previous viewport when widget is closed.

I have looked at this solution- but what I need is to be even more dynamic.
[Dynamic viewport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8469255/dynamic-viewport)
changing the scale on widget open and close.

Comment: cant you do the opposite, check the viewport and scale your fonts?

Comment: I need to scale fonts + images. wanted to see if there is a simpler solution. anyway - it seems like i need to handle some several scales.